# svn 1.8.x for OS X, serf configure fail

Tags: xcode, macos, svn

I am trying to upgrade svn on OS X from 1.7.x to 1.8.x.
I follow the instruction of this post http://samoldak.com/updating-to-svn-1-8-for-mac-os-x-10-8/
While i am doing

```
cd serf/
./configure
```

It shows

> checking for gcc...
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
>   checking whether the C compiler works... no

But it seems it does not work for the latest Xcode environment.
The compiler path should be

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc

But the serf configure is trying to find it in the wrong path.
How to do the configure to make it find the correct compiler path?

Comment: env CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang configure ...

Comment: @hd1 thanks for your quick response, but i didn't get it. I tried to env CC=/....   Then execute ./configure , but it still showed the same error. Can you provide more clear info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solution:
1. To export the env settings for CC and CPP

```
export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
export CPP='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -E'
```

2. To make a symbolic link for the path

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
ln -s XcodeDefault.xctoolchain OSX10.9.xctoolchain
```

The 2nd solution is suggested, it can save lots of time to fix the similar issues coming afterwards.